# Why it is named blue screen error when there was no blue screen appearance in this event?

Tags: windows, boot, bsod

My internet got disconnected. I removed my Ethernet cable and plugged it to the required port and then the light started glowing showing that I can access my internet now. I tried to access the Internet but suddenly my computer got stuck (hung). I waited for 5 minutes but it wasn't responding, so I rebooted. The following is the error reported by Windows. I hadn't have any blue screen appearance in this event  Why does Windows call it "Blue screen error."

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  BlueScreen   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1   Locale ID:   1033
>
> Additional information about the problem:   BCCode:   124
>   BCP1: 00000000   BCP2:    86280024   BCP3:    00000000   BCP4:    00000000   OS
>   Version:  6_1_7600   Service Pack:    0_0   Product:  256_1
>
> Files that help describe the problem:
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\080714-25677-01.dmp
>   C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-69982-0.sysdata.xml
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: Is this a reoccurring event or are you just interested in this particular case?  What is the OS and version?

Comment: @mdpc OP and tags say Windows, dump says 6.1 = Windows 7 (or possibly Windows Server 2008 R2). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_6.1 Windows NT 6.1 build 7600 comes awfully close to Windows 7 RTM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7#Development_history (bottommost paragraph says Win7 RTM is 7600.16385.090713-1255) and "Service Pack: 0_0" appears to support that.

Comment: upload the file C:\Windows\Minidump\080714-25677-01.dmp to a cloud service (Dropbox, OneDrive). 0x124 = fatal hardware error.

Comment: @mdcp....Sir,This event occurred only one time and never happened before.I am interested to know about the error so that next time i can figure out myself and as a computer science student i need to know all this stuff...That's the reason for the above doubt..Thank you for the valuable info

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560672%28v=VS.85%29.aspx I need the dump file to debug this.

Comment: Sorry but we are not going to be able to teach you "all this stuff" here. I suggest starting with the _Windows Internals_ book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you didn't see the blue screen with your eyes doesn't mean it didn't happen.

Windows is set to reboot on blue-screen by default, so it may have done that -- faster than you could see, and then it worked properly after the reboot, so you just never noticed.

That's why it also logs it. ;)

Comment: The OP says the system froze. After some time, the OP forced a reboot. I don't see how a BSOD auto-reboot would enter into that picture.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling If he rebooted it, and it BSoDed and then rebooted again on its own, it could easily seem like one prolonged reboot. REgardless, if there's a log of a bluescreen error, then there was a bluescreen error... :)